# Is there a way to encapsulate a variable with a method with a repeatable action?

Tags: vimscript, repeated-commands

I am trying to encapsulate variables with a method. For example, I am converting this:

```
return variable1;
```

To this:

```
return verify(variable1);
```

Is there a way to quickly repeat this action (ideally with the dot command or a macro of some sort) for other variables?

Comment: Something like `:%s/return \(\i*\);/return verify(\1);/`?

Comment: @muru omg, that was brilliant!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you already have the [surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin, you can do `ysiwfverify<CR>`. Tim Pope has another plugin called [repeat](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat) that lets you repeat surround commands with `.`.

Without any plugin or setup, you can simply do `ciwverify(<C-r><C-o>")<Esc>` and repeat with `.`.

Comment: @romainl Nice, +1! Just a minor suggestion, for the 2nd solution `ciwverify(<C-r>")<Esc>`. When I use it, the dot register is filled with `verify(variable1)` (assuming the word under the cursor was `variable1`). Which means that when I hit dot on a second variable, let's say `variable2`, it's replaced with `verify(variable1)` whereas I wanted `verify(variable2)`. However, if I prefix the unnamed register with `<C-o>` (or `<C-p>`), it works because then the dot register contains `verify(^R^O")`. So, to make the 2nd solution repeatable with dot, `ciwverify(<C-r><C-o>")<esc>` could be used.

Comment: @user9433424, very good point. Let me update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use macros (I love macros!).

First put `return` in the search register: `/return<CR>` or `:let @/="return"`

Then record your macro:

```
qqnwiverify(<Esc>ea)q
```

which can be decomposed like this

```
qq start recording in the register q
n  go to the next occurence of the word in the search register (here 'return')
w  go to the beginning of the word following 'return'
i  enter insert mode
verify( input the function which will encapsulate your variable
e  go to the end of the word after the bracket
a  enter insert mode after the word
)  input the closing bracket
q  stop recording
```

You can then execute the macro with `@q` and repeat it with `@@`.

---

**Edit** Thanks to @Nobe4 you can even make it one keystroke shorter this way:

```
qqnwiverify(<c-o>w)q
```

`<c-o>` allows to go into normal mode for only one command and then go back automatically to insert mode.

Comment: instead of using `<Esc>ea` you can use `<c-o>w` :)

Comment: @Nobe4 here comes the vimgolf :-) Thanks for the suggestion I'll edit my answer.